# RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop while using tkinter.simpledialog

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import tkinter.simpledialog

def showDialog(evt):
    dlg = tkinter.simpledialog.SimpleDialog(root,text='Test!', buttons=['OK'])
    dlg.go()

def test():
    threading.Thread(target=root.event_generate, args=('<<showDialog>>',)).start()

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.bind('<<showDialog>>',showDialog)
tkinter.Button(text = 'showDialog',command = test).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I run this code with Python3.4

The First time I click showDialog Button it work perfectly

but if I press OK and click the button again,it raise a RuntimeError:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1501, in event_generate
    self.tk.call(args)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

I'm learning python recently，this code is just a demo.I want to do some work after press the button in sub-thread，because it will cost a few second and I don't want to stuck the UI. When the work is done,it will show a dialog.?

Can someone please tell me how can I do this using tkinter and why this problem occur?

Thanks！And sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing threads with GUIs, and in particular tk, is tricky.  I do not know all the rules, but unpredictable exceptions and deadlocks are two of the problems.  I am a bit surprised that generating an event in a separate thread from the main thread and mainloop worked even once.  (Why are you trying that?)  A simplified function that run in the same thread does work consistently.

```
def test():
    root.event_generate('<<showDialog>>')
```

Comment: this code is just a demo.I want to do some work after press the button in sub-thread，because it will cost a few second and I don't want to stuck the UI.

Comment: When the work is done,it will show a dialog.How can I do this using tk?

Comment: Possibility 1: Do work in separate thread that sets 'done' variable to true when done.  In the meanwhile, monitor 'done' with main-thread callback that checks every second (or half-second, or whatever interval) and shows dialog when thread is done.

Comment: Possibility 2: Do the work in the main thread in small pieces in an idle task that gives control back to the mainloop after each piece of work.